# Images in Firebase Recycler View is gone when scrolling

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I made kind of SNS that has text and picture.

when user upload pic, firebase recycler view shows a image.

I works for me properly.

The problem occurs when I scroll down, and up
the image that shows in first time is gone.

my image size in xml is fixed 300dp, 300dp like below in recyclerviewitem

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="310dp"

            android:id="@+id/iv_board_attached"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blank"/>
```

to know if user upload image or not, i put the code in populateViewHolder

```
 if(board.attachedPic.equals("") || board.attachedPic.equals(null)){
                            noticeBoardViewHolder.goneAttached();
                        }
                        else {

 noticeBoardViewHolder.setAttached(board.attachedPic);
                        }
```

and in ViewHolder, I tried two ways to solve the problem. boardAttached.setVisibility(View.GONE) and boardAttached.setImageDrawable(null)

```
 public void goneAttached() {
            //boardAttached.setImageDrawable(null);
            boardAttached.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =  
  boardAttached.getLayoutParams();
            //params.width = 0;
            //params.height = 0;
            //boardAttached.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        public void setAttached(String text) {
            attachedString = text;

            Glide.with(mContext).load(attachedString)
                    //.override(310,310)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.blank)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .into(boardAttached);
        }
```

I think the reason that image is gone when scrolling is changing image size in recycler view when scrolling.

when I don't fix image size ('wrap content') and using boardAttached.setImageDrawable(null);, there is empty place in recycler view.

is there problem or best way to show images that shows selectively?

Please help me!

thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm having similar issue.